# How to group tests in MSpec?

Tags: mspec

Could you help me please with my problem.

I am working on a project. For tests I use MSpec.
Is it possible to group test. So when I run test runner they should be tested by groups
i.e. for proper way:

1) When registering user, I provide different password and confirmation password

- should return error message

2) When registering user, I provide all needed information
» user should be registered
» user should be redirected to home page

3) When getting tags tree, I get tags tree

- we should see tags tree

But in my case it works like:

1) When registering user, I provide different password and confirmation password

- should return error message

3) When getting tags tree, I get tags tree

- we should see tags tree

2) When registering user, I provide all needed information

- user should be registered
- user should be redirected to home page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only place contexts are grouped right now is in the HTML report. You need to use the `[Subject]` attribute and provide the same text or type name for contexts that need to be grouped.

On an unrelated note, I would name your contexts/specifications differently:

```
User registration, When providing different password and confirmation password
  » should display an error message

User registration, When providing all information needed (What's "all" information?)
  » should register the user
  » should redirect to the home page

Tags tree, When getting the tags tree
  » should display the tags tree
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please have a look at my edited answer and consider the changed naming. I think it's a good idea to stick with "should" at the beginning of each specification and not to use things like "I", "we" and "see". In the literal meaning, "see" is especially hard to translate into code, whereas "display" is pretty easy to assert.